# PySNMP form dictionary from table

Tags: python-3.x, snmp, pysnmp

I am trying to output the `ifTbale` table from a Cisco switch using the `PySNMP` module.

Here is my current code:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

for (errorIndication,
     errorStatus,
     errorIndex,
     values) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                          CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
                          UdpTransportTarget(('172.20.19.14', 161)),
                          ContextData(),
                          ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifIndex')),
                          ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifDescr')),
                          ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifType')),
                          ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifSpeed')),
                          lexicographicMode=False):

    print('======================')

    for v in values:
        print(str(v))
```

So this works, as it outputs following:

```
======================
IF-MIB::ifIndex.10028 = 10028
IF-MIB::ifDescr.10028 = FastEthernet0/28
IF-MIB::ifType.10028 = 'ethernetCsmacd'
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.10028 = 100000000
======================
IF-MIB::ifIndex.10029 = 10029
IF-MIB::ifDescr.10029 = FastEthernet0/29
IF-MIB::ifType.10029 = 'ethernetCsmacd'
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.10029 = 100000000
======================
IF-MIB::ifIndex.10030 = 10030
IF-MIB::ifDescr.10030 = FastEthernet0/30
IF-MIB::ifType.10030 = 'ethernetCsmacd'
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.10030 = 10000000
...
```

I would like to eventually change this into a function, but at the moment I am wondering how I can get this into a nested dictionary.

I would like the data in the following format:
`{ifIndex{ifDescr, ifType, ifSpeed}}`

which would look like this:
`{10028{ifDescr: 'FastEthernet0/28', ifType: 'ethernetCsmacd', ifSpeed: '100000000'}}`

I am unsure how to tackle this problem though, as I am unable to build the dictionary.

EDIT:
I have managed to get a dictionary with the following code:

```
print('======================')
raw_dict = {str(v).split('.')[0].split(':')[2]: str(v).split('.')[1].split()[2] for v in values}
print(raw_dict.items())
if_dict = {raw_dict['ifIndex']: {k: v} for k, v in raw_dict.items()}
print(if_dict)
```

But it is not iterating through all the values in `raw_dict`.

This is the output:

```
======================
dict_items([('ifSpeed', '100000000'), ('ifIndex', '10048'), ('ifDescr', 'FastEthernet0/48'), ('ifType', "'ethernetCsmacd'")])
{'10048': {'ifType': "'ethernetCsmacd'"}}
======================
dict_items([('ifSpeed', '1000000000'), ('ifIndex', '10101'), ('ifDescr', 'GigabitEthernet0/1'), ('ifType', "'ethernetCsmacd'")])
{'10101': {'ifType': "'ethernetCsmacd'"}}
======================
dict_items([('ifSpeed', '1000000000'), ('ifIndex', '10102'), ('ifDescr', 'GigabitEthernet0/2'), ('ifType', "'ethernetCsmacd'")])
{'10102': {'ifType': "'ethernetCsmacd'"}}
======================
dict_items([('ifSpeed', '4294967295'), ('ifIndex', '10501'), ('ifDescr', 'Null0'), ('ifType', "'other'")])
{'10501': {'ifType': "'other'"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to build a dict like this:

```
{10028: {ifDescr: 'FastEthernet0/28',
         ifType: 'ethernetCsmacd',
         ifSpeed: '100000000'}}
```

For that you need MIB object name (e.g. `ifDescr`), MIB object instance ID (e.g. `10028`) and SNMP object value (e.g. `FastEthernet0/28`). Let me propose the following code to weed out these components from SNMP response var-bindings:

```
myDict = collections.defaultdict(collections.defaultdict)

for varBind in varBinds:
    varName, varValue = varName
    mibName, objectName, objectInstanceId = varName.getMibSymbol()

    idx = '.'.join([str(indexPart) for indexPart in objectInstanceId])

    myDict[idx][objectName] = varValue
```

Keep in mind that the code above implies that PySNMP has MIB(s) for response OIDs loaded so it could turn response OIDs into symbolic values like `ifDescr`.

I'm not sure what do you mean by "not iterating through all the values".